# Redirected to the Homepage when removed www. from URL

Tags: php, magento, url, redirect

Say, My Website is : www.example.com

I have one page : www.example.com/contactus

If I remove "www." from above url, means : example.com/contactus

It redirects me to the homepage. Why ??

Checkout Following Image of .htaccess :

[image]

What is the Solution for it ??

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rule doing the redirection?

Comment: @Ander2 : no dude, i am using magento framework.

Comment: Probably you have redirectios on your http server configuracion (.htaccess) or probably you have a redirection in your DNS configuration.

Comment: means you want me to copy all content to here ?

Comment: @LuFFy it would be useful to see `.htaccess` contents

Comment: Ok i have attached snap of my htaccess

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suspect this is nothing to do with mod_rewrite, but Magento itself.  Navigate to `System->Configuration->Web` in admin.  Under `URL Options` you most likely have `Auto-redirect to Base URL` set to yes.  Your base URL's under `Secure` and `Unsecure` are likely `http(s)://www.example.com/` rather than `http(s)://example.com/`.  When accessing the store via `example.com` it doesn't match the base URL so you get redirected to `www.example.com`.

Comment: No its nothing related to secure or non-secure urls for my site
Because it does not have SSL certificate..By the way Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you actually read my answer, it's nothing to do with SSL, I was pointing out the `Auto-redirect to Base URL` admin setting (which has now also been pointed out by someone else).  You get redirected to your base URL if it doesn't match the browser URL.

Answer (score 1):

Check your .htaccess file for something similar to the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

You can change the second line to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And it will instead redirect to whatever page you requested without the 'www' and put the 'www' back in front.

If you don't find it, you may have a redirect set up in the Magento admin or some other configuration set in your httpd.conf or virtual hosts file.

**Update**

Try adding this to your .htaccess file and see if it fixes your issue (please test in a development environment first):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: please checkout my .htaccess file snapshot.

where i have to do your changes ??

Answer (score 0):

The issue seem to be that you are using the building magento feature 'Auto-redirect to Base URL' in Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Web

[image]

But this feature seem to be misleading, because it DOES NOT seem to append the `url path` (only redirect you to the base url `http://www.site.com` instead of `http://www.site.com/path/to/xyz.html`).

**So the quick fix would be to use [.htaccess rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15389225/1191288).**

Take a look baseUrl which is the url to be redirected to

```
$baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(
    Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB,
    Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()
);

....

Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
        ->setRedirect($baseUrl, $redirectCode)
        ->sendResponse();
```

See /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php

```
/**
 * Auto-redirect to base url (without SID) if the requested url doesn't match it.
 * By default this feature is enabled in configuration.
 *
 * @param Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request
 */
protected function _checkBaseUrl($request)
{
    if (!Mage::isInstalled() || $request->getPost()) {
        return;
    }

    $redirectCode = (int)Mage::getStoreConfig('web/url/redirect_to_base');
    if (!$redirectCode) {
        return;
    } elseif ($redirectCode != 301) {
        $redirectCode = 302;
    }

    if ($this->_isAdminFrontNameMatched($request)) {
        return;
    }

    $baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(
        Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB,
        Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()
    );
    if (!$baseUrl) {
        return;
    }

    $uri = @parse_url($baseUrl);
    $requestUri = $request->getRequestUri() ? $request->getRequestUri() : '/';
    if (isset($uri['scheme']) && $uri['scheme'] != $request->getScheme()
        || isset($uri['host']) && $uri['host'] != $request->getHttpHost()
        || isset($uri['path']) && strpos($requestUri, $uri['path']) === false
    ) {
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()
            ->setRedirect($baseUrl, $redirectCode)
            ->sendResponse();
        exit;
    }
}
```